# Evaluating a set of rules defined in a string

Tags: c#

I made a system that creates a simple string with Function/Response format, example:

```
Check('Value'):ShowImage(@)|Check('Value'):OtherFunction(@)....and so on
```

Where `Check` is the name of a function, `Value` is the parameter, `ShowImage` is the name of a Response function, `@` is the entry paremeter (result of the previous function). The pipe splits another Function/Response pair that fires if the first `Check('Value')` function once "checked" were not satisfied (say, if the parameter was not accomplished the `Check` condition the function is invalid and hence the Response part in the first Function/Response pair is not executed, so system keep trying Functions awaiting to find the one that executes the right Response).

The way the application should work is to evaluate each rule (similar to a JavaScript eval function) and take appropriate action based on function results.

At first glance, it looks complicated, because first of all I need to cast the string to the right real C# function that will actually process the condition. Therefore, depending on the function result, decide where to point to execute my Response function.

Furthermore: This is just the kind example, because there are functions as `*` that represent something like: "any condition is true" what in almost all cases this function is the last in the chain (the default function).

That's my problem, I can't realize what is the easiest way to cope with this problem.
Maybe a chain of delegates? Lambdas? Anonymous stored into a structure...

Could you give me your measure/advise? Where to start?

Comment: It is not completely clear what your problem is. If I got it right, right now you have this "string" which represents a set of rules and actions, which should be parsed using C# and executed? Does it need to look like this? Or is this just a suggestion?

Comment: You got it! This "string" is a set of rules. Then parsed each one as a C# function, and then evaluated, if the function find an "out" argument the Check condition (imagine we are "checking" a dictionary<string, string>), then its reference is the parameter for the response function.

Comment: I have been working on a different but reasonably similar project using NCalc. NCalc allows you to use "Custom Functions" which you can then catch, but it ultimately evaluates to a mathematical expression so your rule set would have to be modified to support that. Anyways it's kind of like an Eval function so it may be helpful to you so you don't have to do as much parsing work and could include mathematical formulas in your variables. You could then use it like  (http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the level of extensibility you want to have, I would say the most extensible way would be to use reflection to get method references, after you have parsed the input string.

You can start by splitting your problem into smaller subproblems.

Let's say you are aiming for something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string rules = 
        "Check(Morning):Say(Good morning)|" +
        "Check(Afternoon):Say(Good afternoon)|" +
        "Check(Evening):Say(Good night)";

    // next, you need some **object instances** which will 
    // provide a context for your "test" and "action" methods.
    // you don't want to use static methods if you
    // went through the pain of defining such an architecture!

    // let's say that a "Tester" object has a "Check" method,
    // and an "Executor" object has a "Say" method:

    var tester = new Tester("Afternoon");
    var executor = new Executor();

    // since I suck at regular expressions,
    // I am using plain string methods to split
    // the expression into tokens. You might want
    // to add some validation

    foreach (var rule in rules.Split('|'))
    {
        var result = Parse(rule, tester, executor);
        if (result.TestPassed)
        {
            result.Execute();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

A "result" as it's used above would then have an interface like this:

```
public interface IResult
{
    // returns true if a test is fulfilled
    bool TestPassed { get; }

    // executes the related action
    void Execute();
}
```

And, if you want to delegate actual actions to some unknown methods, a reasonable way to implement it would be something like this:

```
public class Result : IResult
{
    #region IResult Members

    private readonly Func<bool> _testMethod;
    public bool TestPassed
    {
        get { return _testMethod(); }
    }

    private readonly Action _actionMethod;
    public void Execute()
    {
        _actionMethod();
    }

    #endregion

    public Result(Func<bool> testMethod, Action actionMethod)
    {
        _testMethod = testMethod;
        _actionMethod = actionMethod;
    }
}
```

What's left is to use some reflection to get the actual methods out of your strings:

```
private static IResult Parse(string rule, object tester, object executor)
{
    // split into test/action
    var tokens = rule.Split(':');

    // extract the method/parameter part for each expression
    var test = GetMethodAndParams(tokens[0]);
    var action = GetMethodAndParams(tokens[1]);

    // use reflection to find actual methods
    var testMethod = tester.GetType().GetMethod(test.Method);
    var actionMethod = executor.GetType().GetMethod(action.Method);

    // return delegates which will simply invoke these methods
    return new Result
    (
        () => (bool)testMethod.Invoke(tester, new object[] { test.Param }),
        () => actionMethod.Invoke(executor, new object[] { action.Param })
    );
}
```

That is, more or less, your program's skeleton. You should be able to fill in the missing parts yourself, as an exercise. If you have problems, I can update the answer later.

A `GetMethodAndParams` method should split the input string into a Tuple (or your custom class) which contains the method name and its params as plain strings. `Tester` and `Executor` classes can also be implemented trivially.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a pattern along the lines of the .NET `TryParse()` methods. In that case, you would modify your check method to have an out parameter that is the value (represented in your example by `@`).

```
int result;

if(Check('Value', out result))
    ShowImage(result);
else(Check('Value2', out result))
    OtherFunction(result);
```

Comment: So so ... but I'm sure there are a better infrastrucutre to solve the situation, I was thinking in a chain of delegates, but I don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm back here to post what I've done few weeks ago to solve this situation.
It was easy.

Regex class provide few options, one of those is *"Explicit Catpure"*, all streams with the form (?) can be handled as strong typed parameters so, if the named group "IsNotEmptyorNull" then the function is present and it is promotable to casting using the form Enum.Parse("").

Snipet:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<function>Check|BooleanOp)\('(?<param>[\w]+)'\){1}:(?<action>[\w]+){1}", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

Match m;
Dictionary<FunctionArray, String> actions = new Dictionary<FunctionArray, String>();

if((m=rx.Match(strStream)).Success)
{
   actions.Add((FunctionArray)Enum.Parse(typeof(FunctionArray), m.Groups["function"].value, true), m.Groups["param"].value);
}
```

Of course, there are lost the action part so I've improved the Dictionary stuff with an specialized Struct that can handle the functions and values as a source for decision taking.

Thanks to all. Ed.